permission for saving pdf Android studio
i created a simple app that generated a pdf with 2 pages now i need to share the pdf and also save it in the device from what i already know it requires permissions to do that.
i am new to this and dont know what to do so i watched some tutorials and read some google articles and found out that the permission stuff and storage access is change multiple times through out android 9-13 my targeted sdk versions are 29-34.
how can i manage all the changes and ask for permissions?
also i cant find any permission that says for non media files. so do i even need permission or not?
EDIT:
According to this Table i dont need permission to store files that are not photo, video or audio
Data and File Storage Overview
so i can store them in cache directory let the user share and delete it afterwards

Do you really need to save the document to a public location without asking them the filename (You can suggest one though)? I find the simplest and method that has changed the least is Storage Access Framework (SAF). No permissions required to save. See https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html

This code will help you out and five idea for storing the pdf
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { // To Download File for Android 10 and above
            val content = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/ZipApp/")
            }
            val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(
                MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                content
            )
            uri?.apply {
                val responseBody = getResponseBody(url)
                if (responseBody != null) {
                    responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { fileOutStream ->
                            writeOutStream(
                                inStream = inputStream,
                                outStream = fileOutStream,
                                contentLength = responseBody.contentLength(),
                                emitter = emitter
                            )
                        }
                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                } else {
                    emitter.onError(Throwable(errorMessage))
                }
            }
        } else { // For Android versions below than 10
            val directory = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath + "/ZipApp/"
            ).apply {
                if (!exists()) {
                    mkdir()
                }
            }
            val file = File(directory, fileName)
            val responseBody = getResponseBody(url)

            if (responseBody != null) {
                responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                    file.outputStream().use { fileOutStream ->
                        writeOutStream(
                            inStream = inputStream,
                            outStream = fileOutStream,
                            contentLength = responseBody.contentLength(),
                            emitter = emitter
                        )
                    }
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }
            } else {
                emitter.onError(Throwable(errorMessage))
            }
        }

